# Creating the MySQL table from the Java Spring boot @entities / classes, is it even possible?

Tags: mysql, spring

I want to create my Database (MySQL) using my Java Spring boot @entities & classes defined already with all the required fields and associations. Is it possible to do automatically (By a make migration or migrate command mechanism) ? or do i have to explicitly write the SQL queries e.g the Create Table ones.

PS : tools such as flyway arent of a big help as they require to write SQL code despite defined JAVA Code.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot Uses Hibernate under the hood as an ORM mapping tool.

Hibernate indeed has such a feature:

In plain hibernate:

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is the parameter that you're looking for: use the `create` as a value

Other values also can come handy, read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha) for more information

Spring boot names this parameter slightly different but the logic behind stays the same

**Update 1**

*Based on Op's comment:

Unfortunately I don't have any access to code that works with the relational databases. But given Spring boot driven application you probably already have `src/main/resources/application.properties` (or yaml).

So you should: Read [the relevant chapter of spring boot configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

Then,

In the `application.properties` (or yml) put

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

And start the application. It should create the tables during the hibernate startup if everything else is configured correctly.

If

Comment: Would you please provide a full detailed example ?

Comment: What driver to use for mysql ? and what dependencies to install for mysql inside the pom.xml?

Comment: This is a completely different question :) MySQL's official driver seems to be https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: @lopmkipm read this http://www.masterspringboot.com/data-access/jpa/how-to-get-your-tables-automatically-created-with-spring-boot